# Should intermediate tables be clustered and if so, how?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

If a table A has fk1 and fk2, and that table is equally often joined upon with fk1 and fk2, but rarely both at the same time. And supposing that fk1 + fk2 is unique.

Should that table have an index fk1_and_fk2 and should the table be clustered on that index?

Or should that table have an index on fk1, another on fk2 and clustered on one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are only considering querying, then you should have an auto-incrementing primary key and define `(fk1, fk2)`  and `(fk2, fk1)` as unique.  This assumes that these columns are never `NULL`.  Or, you can define it the other way.  (If they are not `unique` you can just define an index.)

This will speed both types of queries.  In addition, queries that use only these columns can directly use the index, without referring to the original data pages.

By having an auto-incremented/identity/generated always/serial primary clustered key, inserts are faster because they always go at the end of the table.  (Of course, you do get the inserts in the middle of the page for the indexes.)

The downsides?

- Inserts (and updates and deletes) will be a tad bit slower because multiple indexes need to be updated.
- This takes much more space than the original table.

A similar alternative is to have one of the pairs be the primary (clustered) index.  The downside to this is the page overflows on new inserts.